# Display a View using form.show() - Logic issue

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc, extjs4.1

`persomview` is the ID of View class.  part of its definition is as follows;

```
Ext.define('ProjPerson.view.person.PersonTab' ,{
    extend:'Ext.tab.Panel',
    alias : 'widget.ptab',
    id:'ptabid', ......
```

Now from another view classes Controller method, i am calling the `PersonTab` to be displayed by using the following code;

```
var form = Ext.getCmp('ptabid');
form.show();
```

then in firebug it says `form is not defined`. How can i solve this ?

Comment: `Ext.getCmp()` looks for a component instance. Just defining a class doesn't mean `Ext.getCmp()` will find it. Is your view class rendered?

Comment: I am able to `form.hide()`, but not `show.show()`. If i could do this, it would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define **itemId** and use it with getCmp

```
itemId:'ptabid',
```

An itemId can be used as an alternative way to get a reference to a component when no object reference is available. http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel-cfg-itemId

if you want to find active tab, you can use

```
Ext.getCmp('center-region').getActiveTab()
```

here 'center-region' is from layout. use appropriate layout region which you use there.